# /usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked wants to execute as root

Tags: pkexec, update-notifier

just curious... about 30 minutes after turning on my laptop I've been suprised by a window asking me for root password. Its content was something like (translated):

```
For executing '/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked' under superuser permissions is requred authorization
```

(Detail: Action was by org.freedesktop.policykit.exec by The PolicyKit Project)

I was just using my browser and not aware of any action I would like to approve as a root so I've canceled the window and take a look in /var/log/auth.log. There was:

```
Dec 17 09:27:43 MYSTATIONNAME pkexec[6036]: MYUSERNAME: Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/MYUSERNAME] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
```

Why would my computer by itself pkexec something as root (well and if it was an appeal for an update it shouldn't run the command itself, or not)? Is it normal behaviour or might it be some sort of (security) incident? Thx for your advices in advance

EDIT: My opinion - it has something to due with update-notification, probably an error. But I am still suprised why it trow a different login window - like https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html - and want my root password. To show the error log?!

(fyi Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, XFCE, security autoupdates on)

Comment: In my case, on ubuntu 20.04 the login window is not responding. Not allowing to proceed or cancel. Anyway to dismiss this window?